# how to display suggestions from the web

Tags: android

I overwite the SearchRecentSuggestionsProvider to make the custom suggestions for my search, but now I need to return the suggestion data from the server instead of the local provider, how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I would say that it is not a good practice but it can be done.

Basically you need to:

```
- override the method query in your content provider
- query your server or whatever for getting the results
- building a cursor out of the results using a MatrixCursor
```

From the doc:

```
If your search suggestions are not stored in a table format (such as an SQLite table)
using the columns required by the system, then you can search your suggestion data for
matches and then format them into the necessary table on each request. To do so, create 
a MatrixCursor using the required column names and then add a row for each suggestion
usingaddRow(Object[]). Return the final product from your Content Provider's query()
method.
```

Hope it will help.